# Cubase 5 won't open projects with Guitar Rig after update 5.5.2

Tags: plugins, cubase

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate and Cubase 5 64-bit. Been working like a charm.

Earlier this week I installed the update to 5.5.2. Afterwards, I noticed that when I created a new project and used Guitar Rig 3 as a VST plugin it was working MUCH more performant! I was amazed!

Then I went to try to re-load an old project that had Guitar Rig 3. Crash. Every time. No matter what.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve my problem, I renamed the VSTPlugins folder in my environment, in my case:

```
[System Driver] \ Program Files \ Steinberg \ Cubase 5 \ VSTPlugins
```

changes to

```
[System Driver] \ Program Files \ Steinberg \ Cubase 5 \ VSTPlugins2
```

Then I re-loaded my project and voila, it loaded! Now, it loaded, but there were errors, in my case:

```
The plug-in "Guitar Rig 3" could not be found for Insert 1 Channel "Guitar"!
```

UPDATE:

I **removed all references to Guitar Rig**, saved the project, and then closed it. Then I ***SHUT DOWN CUBASE***.

Then I changed my VSTPlugins folder to it's original name, and re-loaded Cubase, and then the offending project. Bingo, worked like a charm! The project opened, but I have to re-add my Guitar Rig insert and choose the correct settings. Fortunately, I have presets mapped for most of my songs, but in the case where you don't, you might have some frustration ahead of you.

I hope this saves someone the time I spent messing around with this. I'm glad I didn't re-install Cubase all over again.

***NOTE***

I also noticed this same behavior with Battery 3. Those are the only plugins I installed outside of what comes with Cubase 5.

Comment: Great little how-to here :) good work!

Comment: Thanks! I'm beginning to think my best route is to just uninstall Cubase and re-install everything, maybe using 32-bit instead of 64-bit install. All my plug-ins are 32-bit, I heard that makes a difference.